# Checking if the date/time is less than a date provided?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, strtotime

I'm implementing the following in PHP with stores this string in the DB for the "created_at" column: `Wed, 17 Dec 2014 14:53:02 +1100`.

```
$created_at = date('r', $insta['created_time']);
```

Now I'd only like to do the insert if `$created_at` is more than a certain date, for example:

```
if ($created_at > "Wed, 15 Dec 2014 00:00:00 +1100") { //insert in to db }
```

That doesn't work though. I'd usually use `strtotime()` but unsure how to go about it when the data is set in that format. Also, the column type is `varchar(255)`.

Comment: You cannot store datetime in mysql with this format, is this a `varchar` column?

Comment: "Also, the column type is `varchar(255)`."

Comment: its always better to store datetime as `timestamp` or `datetime` then to show it as you wish

Answer (score 3):

Aside from your question, you need to store datetime data in a datetime column. Mysql has specific functions and formatting for this reason. But, in order to store it will need to be in Y-m-d H:i:s format. Doing this will save you big hassles down the road.

In regards to your question, you can use PHP's DateTime class if you are using PHP version 5.2+.

```
$compareTime = new DateTime('2014-12-15 00:00:00'); //new datetime object//
$createdTime = new DateTime($created_at); //converts db into datetime object//

if ($createdTime > $comparedTime) { ..insert into DB.. }; //compare them//
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing WED in database..just store date with the php function date("Y-m-d H:i:s") and the table field type will be date..

This way mysql automatically give u facility to compare two dates. You can simply use if else statement to compare two dates.

Comment: My guess is that they are storing it in varchar rather than date/datetime. Mysql would not allow it.

Comment: Thanks, I may have to end up only storing the PHP function `date()`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
$created_at = strtotime($insta['created_time']);
$checkdate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); //here we have to insert check date
if($created_at > $checkdate){ 

}
```

Comment: Thanks, although `$created_at = strtotime($insta['created_time']);` stores `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in the datetime field in the DB.

Comment: if you store time 0000-00-00 00:00:00 so. it is small to any time so it your flow not go to if block

Answer (score 0):

for PHP version >= 5.3

Use `date_create_from_format` or [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Although I think [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) would also work but to be sure pass date time format and value to above function. For detail of format see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: Thanks. `$created_at = date_create_from_format($insta['created_time']);` leaves the column in the DB as `0000-00-00`